# Executing a method at recordset level using odoo old api

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to edit odoo inbuilt hr_attendance.py.My problem is following  validation runs for particular record and not the entire recordset. In new api we use @api multi to execute a  recordset.So how can I execute similarly using old api method of odoo 8

```
  def _altern_si_so(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Alternance sign_in/sign_out check.
    Previous (if exists) must be of opposite action.
    Next (if exists) must be of opposite action.
    """
    for att in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        # search and browse for first previous and first next records
        prev_att_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id', '=', att.employee_id.id), ('name', '<', att.name),
                                             ('action', 'in', ('sign_in', 'sign_out'))], limit=1, order='name DESC')
        next_add_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id', '=', att.employee_id.id), ('name', '>', att.name),
                                             ('action', 'in', ('sign_in', 'sign_out'))], limit=1, order='name ASC')
        prev_atts = self.browse(cr, uid, prev_att_ids, context=context)
        next_atts = self.browse(cr, uid, next_add_ids, context=context)
        # check for alternance, return False if at least one condition is not satisfied
        if prev_atts and prev_atts[0].action == att.action:

            return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})

        if next_atts and next_atts[0].action == att.action:  # next exists and is same action.

            return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})

        if (not prev_atts) and (not next_atts) and att.action != 'sign_in': # first attendance must be sign_in

             return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})
        else:
            return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':False})

        return True
```

_constraints = [
         (_altern_si_so, 'Error ! Sign in (resp. Sign out) must follow Sign out (resp. Sign in)', ['action'])]

I want to execute this method for checking validation for entire recordset not just particular record that is being edited or created.

Comment: remove the return from inside for loop and placed it out side of for loop

Comment: hi @Bharti you query is still unclear for me, please edit your question so that i can understand "if I edit a record from middle of a record se...."

Comment: In short validation code runs only for self record or  particular record and not the entire recordset. Running such a validation will slow down the application if we have thousands of record. So is there a method to check this condition only  for list of records being displayed in tree view.(i.e) 1-20, 1-40

Comment: In attendance module we have sign in and sign out rules they are as follows .(First action performed should be a sign in . Previous action and current action should not be same. Next action and current action should not be same). If we import such records it throws error . What I did is, instead of displaying error. I changed the records to red. Now when a user starts correcting these records. Records will change to black. My problem is some records show error due to prev action or next action not knowing that recordset being corrected.